# Keyframes not showing up in Timeline / Graph Editor

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I'm working on a wallpaper right now and I'm trying to edit an animation and I just went to the animation UI and my animation keyframes are neither showing up in the timeline nor in the dope sheet/graph editor. It's showing up in the NLA Editor though. How can I fix it? I tried clicking the little ghost but that didn't help.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Screenshot]